# Can i check in my script files from chrome developer tools workspace to TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, google-chrome-devtools

I have mapped my application source folder to chrome developer tools workspace.

Can I check in my script files from chrome developer tools workspace to TFS?

Comment: Sure, why not? Are you having a problem doing so?

Comment: What is the option in chrome developer tools to checkin to the TFS?